# Using variable created in private Oncreate() in public Intent

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I cannot get the values of the four variables from the private Oncreate method to the public Intent method.

Below class creates a Pie Chart. Now i'm trying to fill this array with data from my SQlite database.  `int[] values = {dimensionPhysical, dimensionMental, dimensionSocial, dimensionSpirituality};`

The database is openend in the oncreate method and I run 4 times the getcount query below.

```
 public int getCount(String rowId) {
 Cursor C =  db.rawQuery("select count {*} from mainTable where " + KEY_DIMENSION + " = " + rowId, null);
return C.getCount();
}
```

Somehow I cannot get the values of the four variables from the private onCreate method to the public Intent method. The piechart is based on the intitial values of 1.

```
public class Balance extends Activity {
static DBAdapter myDb;
public int dimensionPhysical= 1;
public int dimensionMental= 1;
public int dimensionSocial= 1;
public int dimensionSpirituality= 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_balance);
    openDB();
    dimensionPhysical = myDb.getCount("Physical");
    dimensionMental = myDb.getCount("Mental");
    dimensionSocial = myDb.getCount("Social");
    dimensionSpirituality = myDb.getCount("Spiritual");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    closeDB();
}

private void openDB() {
    myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
    myDb.open();


}

private void closeDB() {
    myDb.close();
}

/*
 * UI Button Callbacks
 */

public void onClick_ClearAll(View v) {
    myDb.deleteAll();
}



public Intent getIntent(Context context) {




    int[] values = {dimensionPhysical, dimensionMental, dimensionSocial, dimensionSpirituality};
    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Pie Graph");
    int k = 0;
    for (int value : values) {
        series.add("Section " + ++k, value);
    }

    int[] colors = new int[]{Color.rgb(144, 238, 144), Color.rgb(173,216,230), Color.rgb(255,204,153), Color.rgb(240,204,153)};

    DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
    for (int color : colors) {
        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(color);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
    renderer.setChartTitle("Pie Chart Demo");
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(7);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getPieChartIntent(context, series, renderer, "Pie");
    return intent;
}
```

}

I hope someone here knows how to fix this problem.

Comment: The values are stored in member variables, so they should be visible in the getIntent method. Did you try logging the values using Log.d inside the onCreate to verify what you're getting from the Database?

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping KEY_DIMENSION in single quotes (I guess it's a string):

```
Cursor C =  db.rawQuery("select count {*} from mainTable where " + KEY_DIMENSION + " = '" + rowId + "'", null);
```

In any case, learn to use logcat and even debugger.

Comment: A rowid is a number. Anyway, the problem, as stated, is accessing the four variables.

Comment: Am I missing something? The argument for myDb.getCount("Physical") for example is String. Also look at the method declaration getCount(String rowId).

Comment: It should not be a string. According to the description, `onCreate` works.

Comment: What do you mean "should not be a string"? The variable is a little awkwardly named but it's obviously a String. I'm not sure how the getCount method even works, I have a similar method and it won't work without single quotes when using String...

Comment: The [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) always is a number.

Comment: I get that. But his "rowId" could easily be named "myStringId" and it wouldn't change a thing because it's just a String variable named "rowId", no?

Comment: The name "rowid" is evidence that using the data type `String` was the wrong choice.